# Renci SSHNet not working properly

Tags: ssh, connection, remote-desktop, remote-server

I m working on script which will let me know running status (running/stopped) of desired application on remote desktop (windows server)
my code is doing fine until I have logged in on remote desktop (using "Remote Desktop Connection").. if I close it without logging off.. it continue work fine.. but as I log off from there .. it just stop working .. here one thing I note.. even after logging off when I run command on ssh client... it gives some successful acknowledgement

I do get desired output when remote desktop connection for that server is on from any other computer in network

ALL FOWWLOWING CODE AND OUTPUT IS WHEN I LOG OFF FROM REMOTE DESKTOP CONNECTION

```
string runCommand = "wmic process call create "TestClient.exe";
SshCommand command = ssh.RunCommand(runCommand);
string myData = command.Result;
```

after this myData will have

Executing (Win32_Process)->Create()

Method execution successful.

Out Parameters:

```
instance of __PARAMETERS
{
    ProcessId = [some pid in numeric]; //when I be logged off, this field would not be there.. (case of problem)
    ReturnValue = [some numeric];
};
```

but after doing this when I check status of test client by following code..

```
string rumCommand = "wmic process where "TestClient.exe" get ProcessID, ExecutablePath";
SshCommand command = ssh.RunCommand(rumCommand);
string myData = command.Result;
```

but there will not any running app listed in myData !!!

Connecting ssh client as per follow..

```
string pass = "password";
PasswordAuthenticationMethod PasswordConnection = new PasswordAuthenticationMethod("user_name", pass);
KeyboardInteractiveAuthenticationMethod KeyboardInteractive = new KeyboardInteractiveAuthenticationMethod("user_name");
ConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo(serverIP, port, "user_name", PasswordConnection, KeyboardInteractive);
SshClient ssh = new SshClient(connectionInfo);
if (!ssh.IsConnected)
      ssh.Connect();
```

Comment: I m using Renci SshNet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yeh, It was very simple problem to solve, but was in corner as well. As I had made test client (which I was testing whether they r running or not) running through task scheduler and forgot to tick on checkbox which suggest that it will be running even after Logoff.. checking this checkbox.. All Fine